# Avoid duplicate execution of code in App Delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, appdelegate

I have a piece of code in my App Delegate which notifies my first View Controller that the user wants to be shown something straight away:

```
- (void)notifyAppWithURL:(NSURL *)url {
    if(!url){
        return;
    }
    NSDictionary *dict = [self parseQueryString:[url query]];
    NSString *host = [url host];
    [self notifyApp:host value:dict[@"id"]];
}

- (void)notifyApp:(NSString *)key value:(NSString *)value {
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ShowOnLoad" object:nil userInfo:@{
                                                                                                   key : value
                                                                                                   }];
}
```

Which I trigger from the `didReceiveRemoteNotification` & the `openURL` delegate methods. Everything works fine from those two.

However, it seems that if the app is closed, and this method is called:

`didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and I place the same call:

```
if(launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey]){
    [self notifyAppWithURL:launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey]];
}
```

inside, then two `NSNotification`'s are sent to the View Controller.

Two questions:

How can I solve this issue with duplicate calls to `notifyAppWithURL` in my App Delegate?

Also, is there a better, more broad, solution to handling multiple incoming actions from the user (and then triggering some other action)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation for `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:) says the following:

> If your app had to be launched to open the URL, the app calls the `application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` and `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` methods first, followed by this method.

You're getting the first notification because you call `notifyAppWithURL:` in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, and the second because you call it in `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:`. A simple solution would be to simply remove the call in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`.

As far as your second question goes, there's not really a general way to handle multiple actions resulting in some code being run twice or more. [`dispatch_once`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_once) is the standard way to make sure a block of code is run once and only once for the whole duration of your process, but that's obviously not what you want.